Difference between a private network and a public network with Network Discovery enabled
I want to SMB-share a directory and am wondering if I should make my WiFi network private or keep it public while enabling Network Discovery for public networks, like so:

I am interested in both the difference in terms of privacy and security (e.g. will other people on the network see the directory?) and functionality.
I am sharing the directory using Advanced Sharing and only giving permission to myself (local admin user):


When you configure a network interface, you have 3 options: Public, Private and Work.
These corresponds to firewall profiles too, where a public network is the most restrictive.
When you keep a network as public, Windows Firewall will limit access to many ports and protocols by default.
The question you should ask yourself is not which of the two is better, but which of the two suits your configuration the most.
If the wifi you currently are connected to is shared to strangers, you want to consider public. But if that wifi is in your own home, and only your family and maybe friends will connect to it, private could be a better choice.
Do note that even if you select public, it is possible to completely reconfigure it so it works as private. They are just profiles to get you started, tailoring to a specific scenario. The problem with altering a profile so it works like another profile, is that if you ever want to switch to that situation, you no longer have that profile for you ready made.
If you only make a small modification, it is perfectly fine to do that to public, but in general, you would want to select the profile suitable first, then make any changes you still need at that point.
